# How to send a file to the server using multipart/form-date via Swift

Tags: php, ios, swift, http, byte

How do I send a file to the server using the Swift language? I send the file to the server and the global variable $_FILES (PHP) does not see the downloaded file. In this case, if I send a request from any other Sender Package, (for example ARC). Then the global array successfully displays the transferred POST by the file method. What's wrong with that ??

```
            // SEND DATA
            let boundary = "--------------------------684819564013531921146535"

            data = AppDelegate.createBody(boundary: boundary,
                                          data: data,
                                          mimeType: "image/png",
                                          filename: "FF4D00-0.8.png")

            let headers = [
                "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)",
                "Content-Length":"\(data.count)"
            ]

            HttpURLConnection.request(type: 1, command: "upload/img", headers: headers, body: data, complition: { (error, data) in
                if error == nil && data != nil {                   
                      print(data)                                   
                }                                                    
             })
```

An here is the function that creates the body of the request

```
// create body for http request
static func createBody(boundary: String,
                data: Data,
                mimeType: String,
                filename: String) -> Data {

    var body = Data()
    body.append("\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"FF4D00-0.8.png\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.append("P".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
    body.append(boundary.appending("--").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)

    print("size is \(body.count)")

    return body as Data
}
```

Here is work:

[example result sent file via ARC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDT9D.png)

Comment: Really when the question concerns something not having a template, then no one can answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com//Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#downloading-data-to-a-file) library. Well documentated, see for example:

```html
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```